# Is it possible to display Google accounts in a BottomSheet instead of a pop-up?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-signin

I noticed this in an Android application, when using Google's method to sign up for the application, the accounts appeared in a BottomSheet instead of a pop-up, as is commonly seen. I couldn't find anything like this on the internet. Do you have any ideas?

[Show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9RQo.jpg)

Personally, I use Flutter. If you have any resources related to this for Flutter or even for Native Android/iOS, I'm interested!

*I'm not sure which technology the application was created with. I didn't do any reverse engineering.*

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Credential Manager APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/credential-manager) for native Android. The bottom sheet can used for both sign up and sign in using "Sign in with Google". Make sure to check for authorized accounts with setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts in an initial call to check if the user has used an account to sign in before.

If not, you can make the call with it set to false to allow the user to choose an account for sign up.

And if the user dismisses the bottom sheet, you can still add a Sign in with Google button to your login page.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example in Android Jetpack Compose

You can use `BottomSheetScaffold` follow this [link](https://www.composables.com/tutorials/bottomsheet)

Step 1: Create a Composable for list of Emails (Eg: EmailListComposable)

Step 2: Add that Composable to

> BottomSheetScaffold -> sheetContent

It will look something like this

```
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
....
        sheetContent = {
          //Add your EmailListComposable
        },
        topBar = {
           //Your toolbar
        },
        content = { //Your Content })
```

Step 3: You can use this to show/hide the bottom sheet on any onClickListener etc

Add

```
val sheetState = rememberBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = BottomSheetValue.Collapsed
    )
```

then

```
    if (sheetState.isCollapsed) {
                    sheetState.expand()
                } else {
                    sheetState.collapse()
                }
```